# How to run a program like sublime text 4 Editor from Terminal\PowerShell on windows computer?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, terminal, text-editors, sublime-text

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSdCC.png)

I tried "start subl" in the terminal, but it didn't work.
is someone can help me figure this out I would be grateful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file `subl.exe` is probably not found.

You options are:

- Use the full path, such as in
  `"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 4\subl.exe" path-to-file`
- Add to the PATH the folder `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 4`
- Add to your
  [PowerShell profile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2)
  the command
  `Set-Alias subl 'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 4\subl.exe'`

Comment: See this also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440639/sublime-text-from-command-line